# How to associate these classes in UML Class Analysis Diagram?

Tags: uml, data-modeling, model-associations

I'm trying to design UML Analysis Class Diagram for a college project. My UML Diagram looks like this:
[image]

I have encountered two different problems:

1. User can have multiple roles. A user with Manager role can manage other users and their roles. How to illustrate this association in UML?
2. User uses SwipeCard to access a room. How to show this association in UML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a really good start to an analysis model. Some things I would do:

- Reify the association between `User` and `Role` (or make it an association class) called `Role Assignment`.
- Add a verb-phrased property name to every end of every association. For example, `Manager` *authorizes* `Role Assignment` and `Role Assignment` *authorized by* `Manager`.

Here's an example first cut, off the top of my head:

[image]

I left off a bunch of stuff, including operations, which I would suppress for validation with SMEs. I can't do *all* the work for you!

Comment: Sounds good idea. I suggest you add a image or a ascii that displays your UML Diagram, in order to understand mroe your answer

Comment: @Jim L. Yes, please add a UML diagram, that will be easier to understand.

Comment: Also, I have updated the SwipeCard part because it is quite simple. The User with Manager role part is still ambiguous, please check: [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6_hNGJUq8_2RzBraENZS29RU1k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @user3566211: is this easier to understand? One rather important point to an analysis model is to capture the domain accurately and validate the understanding with non-technical experts. I think this is pretty easy to understand, as it's in plain English.

Answer (score 1):

1. Give the Role class some manage methods which are used for the intended purpose. But behavioral context is better shown in activity or sequence diagrams where you can elaborate what the "manage" does.
2. Add an association from User to SwipeCard and name it "use". Further add an association from SwipeCard to Room and name it "opens".

Re 1:

[image] these are the methods to manipulate roles and

[image] shows how the manager uses them. The constraint tells that only the manager may use this method.

Comment: Thomas, the second part of your answer is very convincing and I have decided to go by your suggestion. However, I'm not getting your point in part 1. Would you mind showing this in UML?

Comment: See my addition. Good, you asked. I explained it wrongly, but after drawing it, the error was obvious and I could correct it.

Comment: Thomas, you are suggesting this by using sequence diagram, I want to accomplish this with Analysis diagram, please check this updated diagram: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6_hNGJUq8_2RzBraENZS29RU1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: An analysis also involves description of behavior. You could go with just a static class (/analysis) diagram and add comments. But using behavioral diagrams will clarify things much more.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Quick Answer**

Make the `Role` class, not the `Manager` class.

**Long Boring Answer**

I had a similar case, but, eventually, had a similar `Manager` class, and later add a `MiddleManager` class that could also manage other classes.

```
..........................
..+-----------------+.....
..|      User       |--+..
..+-----------------+..|..
...........^...........|..
........../ \..........|..
..........\ /..........|..
...........v...........|..Can Manage Other Users
...........|...........|..
...........|...........|..
...........|...........|..
..+-----------------+..|..
..|      Role       |--+..
..+-----------------+.....
..| [+] CanManage() |.....
..+-----------------+.....
..........................
```

So, I move a function or properties `canManage()`  to the `Role` class.

As @Thomas Kilian mention, your question is more a behaviour feature, than a structural feature. Behaviors are represented as methods or properties, in a class diagram.

UPDATE:

```
..........................
..+-----------------+.....
..|      User       |--+..
..+-----------------+..|..«Can Manage Other Users»
..| [+] CanManage() |--+..
..+-----------------+.....
...........^..............
........../ \.............
..........\ /.............
...........v..............
...........|..............
...........|..............
...........|..............
..+-----------------+.....
..|      Role       |.....
..+-----------------+.....
..........................
```

Another version may include a self referenced association.

Comment: a User with Manager cannot only manage roles but also other users. I'm trying to show this in UML. I understand your point regarding this problem being behavioral, but I think there still is some way to show this in UML Class Analysis diagram, although not in detail.

Comment: how about a self-association from User to User only. Since a User with Manager role can manage other users, that user can also manager their roles. But is it a valid assumption or approach?

Comment: Yes, a self-association also apply. Remember there can be more than one way to do things or make a model, and all of them can be correct.

Comment: Just give me your final word or opinion on this approach, should I go for it?

Comment: Yes, is ok. But, if your homework, includes other stuff like sequential diagram or activity diagram, then maybe other solution may apply. If its just a class diagram, then the self-association diagram its ok.

Comment: It is part of my project that I'm doing for my Object Oriented Analysis and Design course. It does involve use case, activity and sequential diagrams. But these are based on Class Analysis diagram, so I'll design them accordingly.

Comment: A self association from `User` to `User` for role management is incorrect as an analysis model because it does not convey the rules of the domain properly. A subject matter expert will tell you it's wrong. Such a model could be correct as a _design_ model, however, assuming you have logic to prevent unintended consequences. I wouldn't blame a professor for taking off points.

Comment: @umlcat: what do you think the stereotype «Can Manage Other Users» means? Why not model this with normal UML semantics?

Comment: @Jim L. Was a syntax error. Not intended to be a stereotype, but an association label.

Comment: @umlcat: a very odd way to model things, _especially_ for an analysis model to be validated with SMEs.