# Class diagram from use case diagram

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I have the following use case diagram

[image: Use case diagram]

What is the best way to create a class from this diagram?

I've tried creating two main classes (`UserManager` and `ContentManager`) but the whole class structure looks wrong and illogical.

Can anyone provide a simple example to help me?

[Edit] Below I've pasted my class diagram. What would you change or what do you think about it?

[image: My class diagram]

Comment: Can you include some more information on the classes that you've created?

Comment: FWIW: Neither Login nor Logout are use cases. "{ must be logged in}" is a constraint you may apply to UCs. Use verb/substantive in English. The associations for the actors seem pointless. I guess you meant generalization instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Class` represents a set of things from the problem domain, not an arbitrary bucket of code. For example, you should have classes like `Comment`, `Article`, `Announcement`, and `Advertisement`. You should have associations between pairs of related classes, each association having named properties and multiplicities. The result should look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35755928/how-to-associate-these-classes-in-uml-class-analysis-diagram/35757728#35757728). You will eventually give each of those classes responsibilities. That is how object oriented analysis and design works.

Class names ending in the word `Manager` indicate you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I've edited post and pasted my class diagram. Could you check it? I'm new to UML.

Comment: You have meant starting a new topic?

Comment: Yes. Your new question is too large and different from the one on this page. I would replace your edit with a link to a follow-on question.

Comment: @sadasdadad: Any reason why you accepted my answer without upvoting it too? Feel free to leave a comment so I can improve my answer.

Comment: I'd like ask you to present a class structure because I can't imagine whole diagram. I have no idea how it should look. Ofc you can leave out properties and methods.

Comment: Didn't I just do that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801987/uml-class-diagram-for-simple-web-portal)?