# UML class diagram for simple web portal

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case

I want to ask you about my class diagram. I'm making a class diagram for simple web portal for my weekend university studies. Is it made correctly? What would you change if I you were mine? Use cases you can find here [Class diagram from use case diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797303/class-diagram-from-use-case-diagram).

Should I create each user class separately? I mean Admin class, Redactor class, Moderator class etc. I've used privileges field (see User class) to simulate each user's role. Is it correct?

I imagine that ContentManager class holds User class instance and it is used inside Article, Announcement, Advertisement and Comment class to check whether these action is allowed.

[image]

I would be very glad for your answers. Here you can find XML file for WhiteStarUML program [my XML file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B55oduKha-FtaHFmQzlvdHdIVUk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please move your class diagram here.

Comment: I paste it above, but stackoverflow requires to have at least 10 reputation points to publish and show images. I would ask you to click link.

Comment: I edited it for you.

Comment: Np. Where can I do it? I did it in last topic about use cases.

Comment: I look forward to receiving your reply about class diagrams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is create an analysis model of your domain. That model would contain classes like `Article`, `Announcement`, etc., as you have in your current diagram. For an example, please refer to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35757728/2596664) I recently posted to someone else's question. The diagram for that answer is shown again here for your convenience:

[image]

Notice how the model I provided in that answer has nothing like a `UserManager` or a `ContentManager` that just contains code to manipulate other classes. You don't want those, unless people actually play those roles. Notice how it has verb phrases and multiplicities at the ends of every association to tell you why things are related. Notice how there are no mundane CRUD operations on those classes, like create, update, and delete.

Once you have an analysis model in place, then you should allocate actions to the appropriate classes, which will usually mirror your use cases. For example, your `Comment` class might have an `edit()` operation. But it might not. You might consider having an operation called `replaceComment()` in the `Article` class (if that's how your domain works). I don't know how your domain should work because you are missing an analysis model that teaches it to me!

After you complete an analysis model, then I would make a design model that augments it with solution-domain concerns, such as logging a user into the system. [Here is an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461613/game-class-diagram/29462410#29462410) that you may find helpful for moving from analysis to design.

Comment: It's only an example. It is difficult to me to imagine how my class diagram should look. Would you be able to make a drawing which can help me to understand my class diagram? I mean use the classes names which I used in previous post.

Comment: I don't know anything about your domain. Can you list some facts, like the ones in the first set of bullets in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29462410/2596664

Comment: Some guesses: an Author _writes_ many Articles, an Article _contains_ one or more Advertisements, a Reader _leaves_ any number of Comments, a Comment _annotates_ one Article, ...

Comment: A Person _plays_ Role, an Author is a kind of Role, a Reader is a kind of Role, ... ("is a kind of" is specialization / generalization)

Comment: Unlogged user can view articles, comments, adverts and announcements.
Unlogged user can register.and can log in.
Logged user can log out, can leave a comment (or many comments), edit, remove it etc.

I thought that use cases can explain everything well. Am i correct?
Logged user can reset or change his/her password etc.

Comment: I would reframe that as a Reader _reads_ Article, an Identified Reader _removes_ zero or more Comments. Forget logging in and out and changing passwords. What if an RFID chip in my arm is sufficient for identification? There's no logging in, out, or changing passwords. In an analysis model you model the _problem_, not your _solution_. That's one reason everyone says not to model a "login" use case.

Comment: For instance. Should I create class Reader with methods like showArticle(), showAdvert() etc? I am really sorry for my questions. Our teacher didn't explained it well.

Comment: Forget the operations until you do the analysis model. You're getting confused by not separating concerns.

Comment: Does each actor have their separate class?

Comment: In an analysis model, a person can play roles. Those roles are usually actors in a use case model. But, not all roles interact with the system. For example, a Child on an Insurance Form probably doesn't interact with a system.

Comment: I suggest you try creating an analysis model, then ask for feedback on it in yet another question.

Comment: So my roles are Reader (reads site), Commentator (comments articles), Administrator (manages users) , Redactor (publishes articles), Moderator (comments managing )and Advertiser (adverts managing)

Comment: I don't think a Reader reads a Site. Perhaps a Reader _visits_ Site. Anyway, try making a model in UML.